# Authenticating samba shares with active directory users and groups

Tags: 10.04, samba, likewise, active-directory

I am looking for instruction on how to configure my Ubuntu 10.04 box to allow samba shares access through Active Directory users and groups. I have joined the Ubuntu machine to my AD domain using Likewise-open, however when I enable 'security = ads' in my smb.conf I am getting access denied errors when trying to view shares in windows explorer. Any sugestions?

Answer (score 5):

Try following the official guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/samba-ad-integration.html

I'm guessing you haven't linked the password files, as it says Samba and likewise use separate databases.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good guide, step by step.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ActiveDirectoryWinbindHowto

- First step. install andconfigure kerberos: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/Kerberos
- Next install required packages:
  winbind
  samba
- And if you wish to mount samba folders:
  smbfs
  smbclient
- Then Join the AD domain by editing the /etc/samba/smb.conf file ( follow the guide )

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an answer per se, but I think it's informative (I never tried it).. I have been browsing the ***canonical partner*** repository (for ubuntu 10.10 maverick) and I noticed a package named "***centrifydc***". The description follows:

```
Description: Centrify Express
 Free Active Directory Integration and single sign-on for Ubuntu - Centrify
 Express is the No. 1 choice of IT professionals for Active Directory-based
 authentication and single sign-on to cross-platform systems.
 .
 Centrify Express is not only the quickest and easiest solution to use and
 deploy for integrating Ubuntu systems with Active Directory, but delivers more
 functionality and more to upgrade to than alternative offerings.  And best of
 all - it is free! For more free tools, information and community support check
 out http://www.centrify.com/express
```

An informative website of what you have to do: http://www.centrify.com/blogs/tomkemp/join_ubuntu_to_active_directory_domain.asp

Answer (score 1):

See this it may help you

http://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_&_Active_Directory